# Where are attachments stored when sending text messages

Tags: sms, internal-storage, file-management

Where are the **attached images to text messages stored** on Froyo 2.2.1 ( Samsung Galaxy S , if that should make a difference ) ?

I am asking following problems I have now when sending texts with images attached : [*I can't send a picture attachment together with a text message*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7644/i-cant-send-a-picture-attachment-together-with-a-text-message-any-more-samsung).

**--- UPDATE ---**

I have found the solution to the problem mentioned. Please look at the answer of my other question if you have the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your attachments are stored in the location where they existed before you attached them.  It's possible they might be copied somewhere, but how do you know they are? And how is it relevant?

Comment: @Matthew Read: Are you sure ? When a picture is taken to be attached to a message, it reports that the attachment is too large and that the picture is to be resized. I can imagine that at that time the attachment is created/copied into another location than the original message. I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: Well it might be stored in memory temporarily, but you're right that it might be cached. I'm still just wondering how the cache location is relevant to your problem?

Comment: @Matthew Read: the picture taken is a .jpg file. But, as explained in my other question, when I `view` the attached image, it behaves as a movie of 5 seconds. I was just wondering whether some sort of transformation had taken place, and therefore I could view the attached file in another folder (maybe seeing that it now as a .mov file or something). I really am looking for a solution, here,it's annoying not being able to send a picture message.

Comment: That, i believe, is the media viewer for the Galaxy S. It treats every image sent in an MMS as a "video" for some reason. Another reason why I dislike touchwiz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that no special folder is used to store attachments - strange since I am definitely saw the message 'picture too large - compressing' when trying to send an image via MMS.

I would have expected this to be saved somewhere.

I will accept my own answer here, unless someone else can give some valuable information.